# Configure webpack dev server in .Net Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have been searching for ages trying to find how you would set up a .net core 3 project to use a webpack dev server to serve assets. This would allow things like hot module replacement. If anyone has some boilerplate for accomplishing this that would be great! Below I have included my current dev webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        app: "./wwwroot/src/js/app.js",
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/wwwroot/dist/"),
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors",
                    chunks: "all",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "expose-loader",
                        options: "jQuery",
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "expose-loader",
                        options: "$",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: 1. Current there's no official docs for this since the UseWebpackDevMiddleware() will be removed in .NET 5. But it is still useful in ASP.NET Core 3.0. If you don't care that, this blog(https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/07/05/aspnetcore-hmr/) written by Nate McMaster, who is a member of ASP.NET Core, delivers the solution.

Comment: 2. Another way is to write a custom middleware : e.g.,`UseSpa(builder=>{  builder.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer($"http://localhost:{port}"); })` But that approach requires a lot work e.g., start the dev server/ wait for the dev server is ready/ shut down the server. Unfortunately, the npm task runner classes are all internal, and the Nodejs related service will also be removed in .NET 5. In other words, there is no suitable stable  API to build such a template for the present. After the community creates a new Node.js/npm task runner, I think there should be a stable template.